# Using a thread to update a table automatically in Django

Tags: python, multithreading, django

For my portfolio app using Django I made a thread that pulls out the usd exchange rates for various currencies every 6 hours and updates the database. The program kicks in as soon as the module `module_stock.py` is being imported.

Other than to make  the thread to start in a function call, should I be aware of any disadvantages if this runs in production environment for days, weeks on end? Or in other words is it ok to have this thread running at all time ?

Relevant pieces of code below.

module_stock.py:

```
import threading

UPDATE_INTERVAL = 21600

class WorldTradingData:
    ''' methods to handle trading data
        website: https://www.worldtradingdata.com
    '''
    @classmethod
    def setup(cls,):
        cls.api_token = config('API_token')
        cls.stock_url = 'https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock'
        cls.intraday_url = 'https://intraday.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/intraday'
        cls.history_url = 'https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/history'
        cls.forex_url = 'https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/forex'

    @classmethod
    def update_currencies(cls):
        base_currency = 'USD'
        url = ''.join([cls.forex_url,
                       '?base=' + base_currency,
                       '&api_token=' + cls.api_token,
                       ])
        try:
            res = requests.get(url)
            forex_dict = json.loads(res.content).get('data', {})

        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            forex_dict = {}
            logger.info(f'connection error: {url}')

        for cur in Currency.objects.all().order_by('currency'):
            currency_key = cur.currency
            currency_object = Currency.objects.get(currency=currency_key)
            usd_exchange_rate = forex_dict.get(currency_key, '')

            if usd_exchange_rate:
                currency_object.usd_exchange_rate = usd_exchange_rate
                currency_object.save()


def update_currencies_at_interval(interval=UPDATE_INTERVAL):
    '''  update the currency depending on interval in seconds
         default value is 6 hours (21600 seconds)
    '''
    assert isinstance(interval, int), f'check interval setting {interval} must be an integer'

    wtd = WorldTradingData()
    wtd.setup()
    start_time = time.time()
    current_time = start_time
    elapsed_time = int(current_time - start_time)

    while True:
        if elapsed_time % interval == 0:
            wtd.update_currencies()

        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = int(current_time - start_time)


thread_update_currencies = threading.Thread(
    target=update_currencies_at_interval, kwargs={'interval': UPDATE_INTERVAL})
thread_update_currencies.start()
```

models.py:

````
from django.db import models

class Currency(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    usd_exchange_rate = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1.0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency
```
````

Answer (score 3):

### Keep a base URL

`'https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/'` should be factored out of your URL variables. You can use the Python libraries in `urllib` to safely construct the URLs after, which is preferable to using `join` as you do.

### Don't manually construct a URL

```
    url = ''.join([cls.forex_url,
                   '?base=' + base_currency,
                   '&api_token=' + cls.api_token,
                   ])
```

This is more work than you have to do. Just pass a dict to `requests.get`'s `params` kwarg.

### Don't call `json.loads()`

```
        res = requests.get(url)
        forex_dict = json.loads(res.content).get('data', {})
```

Just call `res.json()`.

### Check your HTTP result

Call `res.raise_for_status()`, or at the absolute least check the status of the result. Currently, there are some failure modes that will not throw from your code at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, which I have now implemented. Any ideas if and how I should implement the thread to update the currencies every six hours...

Comment: Probably the answer is to not do it in Python, and to have a cron job.

Comment: @Reiderien, I have changed the update now using a cron job, updating the Currency table directly with sql.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Feel free to post that in a new question if you want another review :)

Comment: You could use Celery and Beat. This way you could still use the Django ORM, reducing a bit of duplication. (You could also use `sleep` in the above loop, so that the CPU isn't spinning the whole time, but I wouldn't on anything more than a proof of concept.)